# Google Cloud Text To Speech REST API Authentication

Tags: rest, google-authentication, google-text-to-speech

So I want to use the Google Cloud Text to Speech using a simple POST request from my C++ program, the problem is with their authentication. I did create a service account as they mentioned and I got the file containing my private key. But I don't know how can I use it in my POST request to be authenticated ?

POST Url: https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize
and here is my POST body:

{
    "audioConfig": {
    "audioEncoding": "LINEAR16",
    "pitch": "0.00",
    "speakingRate": "1.00"
  },
  "input": {
    "text": "Hello World"
  },
  "voice": {
    "languageCode": "en-US",
    "name": "en-US-Wavenet-E"
  }
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out that I need to create an API Key Credential from the following link:
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=[your-project-name]

and then append "?key=[API_KEY]" to my POST url and the authentication problem is fixed !

Comment: i get an invalid api key any ideas why

Comment: I try to use Speech to Text. I've created and use it in `key` query parameter, but response looks like  as below, there is no transcription.

`"{"totalBilledTime":"15s","requestId":"1275006314905327905"}"`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the path of the JSON file that contains your service account key.

Comment: How can this authenticate my POST request ?

Comment: Sorry misread your post. I’ll update my answer when I have time, but until then I would look at using the [Google C++ API Library](https://github.com/google/google-api-cpp-client). There is some [sample code](https://github.com/google/google-api-cpp-client/blob/master/src/samples/storage_sample_main.cc) that using that libraries Auth module to make requests. My C++ isn’t up to snuff for me to easily condense what you need to do, but like I said when I have time later, I’ll take a look through it and update my answer.